# Unexpected behaviour with print()

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to parse some data out of a `kafka` stream. Below is somewhat what I am doing at the moment.

```
Import /* … */

Object MyObject {
    Def main (args: Array[String]){
        /*spark streaming context set up*/

        val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext,zkQuorum,groupID,[per-topic number of Kafka partitions to consume])
        kafkaStream.persist(/*Storage Level*/)

        val field_1_Retrieved = kafkaStream.parsingFunctionToRetrieveField1().print
        val field_2_Retrieved = kafkaStream.parsingFunctionToRetrieveField2().print
        val field_3_Retrieved = kafkaStream.parsingFunctionToRetrieveField3().print

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

But, here is what I output:

```
-----------------------
Time xxxxxxxxxx ms
-----------------------
field_1_Retrieved
field_1_Retrieved
-----------------------
Time xxxxxxxxxy ms
-----------------------
field_2_Retrieved
field_2_Retrieved
-----------------------
Time xxxxxxxxxz ms
-----------------------
field_3_Retrieved
field_3_Retrieved
```

This seams random, and is surely not what I would expect from my code. It would be something like the following:

```
Time xxxxxxxxxx ms
-----------------------
field_1_Retrieved
field_2_Retrieved
field_3_Retrieved
-----------------------
Time xxxxxxxxxy ms
-----------------------
field_1_Retrieved
field_2_Retrieved
field_3_Retrieved
```

What am I missing from the functioning of `spark` or `kafka` that would cause this behaviour? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: what is the code for `parsingFunctionToRetrieveFieldX()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected behavior. [`print`'s implementation for a DStream](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L731) starts with a timestamp banner. Calling `print` on multiple DStreams will result in multiple banners.

To achieve version #2, you will need to transform the data in the original dstream to the 3 different versions within the same DStream (probably using flatmap).  Given that `parsingFunctionToRetrieveFieldx` is not provided, it's not possible to give additional details on that.